# RANK based on SORT by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, rank

I am trying to group by ID_1 and sort by ID_2 Descending and TotalRevenue Ascending to extract a rank

Please assist how to use both ascending and descending feature in RANK sort function

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

    'ID_1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
    'ID_2':[100,100,35,30,30,20,50,50],
    'TotalRevenue':[9000,2000,750,1000,600,500,500,300]})
  

df['RANK']= df.groupby(['ID_1'])['ID_2','TotalRevenue'].rank(method='dense',ascending=False).astype(int)


Desired output:

ID_1   ID_2   TotalRevenue       Rank
   1   100          9000           2
   1   100          2000           1
   1   35           750            3
   2   30           1000           2
   2   30           600            1
   2   20           500            3
   3   50           500            2
   3   50           300            1
```

Comment: Im not getting any update when ran like you have mentioned, I see below  as the output.
**_**
I am running this in Jupyter

Comment: The output mentioned in the question is my desired output

Comment: Thanks its working, but I want to know why the regular "group by rank" function failed for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sort_values` and assign `cumcount`+1 based on the group

```
out = df.sort_values(['ID_2','TotalRevenue'],ascending=[False,True])
out['Rank'] = out.groupby("ID_1").cumcount()+1
print(out.sort_index())
```

---

```
   ID_1  ID_2  TotalRevenue  Rank
0     1   100          9000     2
1     1   100          2000     1
2     1    35           750     3
3     2    30          1000     2
4     2    30           600     1
5     2    20           500     3
6     3    50           500     2
7     3    50           300     1
```

Comment: Thank anky, any help why the regular "group by rank" function failed for this issue

Comment: @Pav groupby rank of 2 columns would return a dataframe but here we want a series so we manipulated the logic a bit with sort vaues and then just assigned an increamental row per group